# Toggling Up and Down hidden paragraphs; only one works

Tags: jquery

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago, but I'm having the same problem again, and can't figure it out:

I've got 3 divs with customized FontAwesome checkboxes. When I click a checkbox, I want to slideDown() the paragraph that goes below it, then slideUp() the paragraph if it's clicked again. I can only get one paragraph to slide down. When I click the other 2, the first paragraph still still slides down, so I'm thinking I'm having a problem with my jQuery traversal. Again, I'm still a bit of a beginner, so thanks for any resolutions!!

HTML:

```
 <div class="serviceOption">
    <input id="serviceCheckbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="serviceCheckbox"> Technology Audits</label>
 </div>
 <p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is a Tech Audit Paragraph.</p>


 <div class="serviceOption">
    <input id="serviceCheckbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="serviceCheckbox"> Email Audits</label>
 </div>
 <p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is an Email Audit Paragraph.</p>

 <div class="serviceOption">
    <input id="serviceCheckbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="serviceCheckbox"> Service Audits</label>
 </div>
 <p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is a Service Audit Paragraph.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.serviceOption{
    margin: 5% 0; /* SEPARATES DIVS */
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
   display: none;  /* HIDES NORMAL CHECKBOXES SO I CANT INSERT CUSTOM ONES */
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f107';   /* ADDS CUSTOM CHECKBOX */
    color: #e3ab2f;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f106"; 
    letter-spacing: 10px; 
    color: #e3ab2f;
}

#serviceOptionParagraph{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#serviceCheckbox').change(function(){
     var nextParagraph= $(this).closest(".serviceOption").next("#serviceOptionParagraph");    
     if (this.checked){
         $(nextParagraph).slideDown(200);
     } else {
         $(nextParagraph).slideUp(200);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be running into problems by having multiple things with the same id. Try changing

`<p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is a Service Audit Paragraph.</p>`

to

`<p class="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is a Service Audit Paragraph.</p>`

and

`var nextParagraph= $(this).closest(".serviceOption").next("#serviceOptionParagraph");`

to

`var nextParagraph= $(this).closest(".serviceOption").next(".serviceOptionParagraph");`

----------edited solution below-----------
`

```
<div class="serviceOption">
    <input id="serviceCheckbox1" class='togglething' type="checkbox">
    <label for="serviceCheckbox1"> Technology Audits</label>
 </div>
 <p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is a Tech Audit Paragraph.</p>


 <div class="serviceOption">
    <input id="serviceCheckbox2" class='togglething' type="checkbox">
    <label for="serviceCheckbox2"> Email Audits</label>
 </div>
 <p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is an Email Audit Paragraph.</p>

 <div class="serviceOption">
    <input id="serviceCheckbox3" class='togglething' type="checkbox">
    <label for="serviceCheckbox3"> Service Audits</label>
 </div>
 <p id="serviceOptionParagraph"> This is a Service Audit Paragraph.</p>
```

and

```
$('.togglething').change(function(){
     var nextParagraph= $(this).closest(".serviceOption").next("#serviceOptionParagraph");    
     if (this.checked){
         $(nextParagraph).slideDown(200);
     } else {
         $(nextParagraph).slideUp(200);
     }
});
```

`

I added a class to each input so we could still attach a change event to them all at the same time, but now they each have their own unique ID for attaching their own unique label.

Comment: Hm... that didn't seem to do the trick. The I.D.s are still named differently even without the change!

Comment: Aah yup looking at it now and I think that makes sense. Alright so how come all three `<input>`s have the same ID? You have the line `<label for="serviceCheckbox"> Email Audits</label>` three times, and I'm pretty sure each time when it evaluates the `label for=` part, it's traversing the DOM from start to finish, finding the _first_ DOM element where id='serviceCheckbox' (the first one) and then attaching it to that. So no matter what label you click, it's going to toggle the first checkbox because all three labels are attached to it.

Comment: Editing my above answer to fix it, would be too long to paste here.

Comment: That worked @cbrainerd! It was indeed the checkboxes that were the problem. You are a genius and scholar!